# Cannot send data using Bluetooth HC-06 - app stops working

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to create connection between Arduino and Android device. 
I'm using:

- Arduino Leonardo
- Bluetooth Device: HC-06

My Android App should read data sent from Arduino device. Here is the code for Arduino.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

   delay(500);
   Serial.print("#A~");
   Serial1.print("#A~");
}
```

My App is making a connection with Arduino but the thing is that my app crashes when it comes out to receive data from Arduino. It says "Unfortunately BluetoothApp has stoped".

The strange thing is that I can receive data from Arduino using Bluetooth Terminal App for Android.

Here is the code for Android:

```
    package com.example.matt.onresumeapp;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ComunicationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView copyInfo;
    TextView handlerInfo;
    Handler h;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

    private String adress;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private static UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private StringBuilder stBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    final int handlerState = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comunication);

        copyInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.copyInfo);
        handlerInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.handlerInfo);



        h = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);

                if(msg.what == handlerState){

                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    stBuilder.append(readMessage);

                    int endOfLine = stBuilder.indexOf("~");


                    if(stBuilder.charAt(0) == '#'){

                        String dataInPrint = stBuilder.substring(1, endOfLine);
                        handlerInfo.setText(dataInPrint);

                    }

                    stBuilder.delete(0, endOfLine);

                }

            }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    }

    private BluetoothSocket btSocketConnection (BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException{

        return device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent newIntent = getIntent();
        adress = newIntent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ADRESS");


        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(adress);

        try {
            mmSocket = btSocketConnection(device);



        } catch (IOException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket's method failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e){

            try {

                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket's connect() method failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();


    }



    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread{

        private InputStream mmInStream;
        private OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){

            mmSocket = socket;

            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut= null;

            try {

                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e){

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error occurred when creating input stream", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            try {
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

            } catch (IOException e){


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error occurred when creating output stream", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        }


        public void run() {
            super.run();

            byte[] mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes;

            while (true){
                try{
                    numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);

                    String readMessage = new String(mmBuffer, 0, numBytes);
                    h.obtainMessage(handlerState, numBytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e){

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Input stream was disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to solve this problem for couple of days but without any progess...
I'd very grateful for any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

Just changed handler method to this:

```
 h = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);

                if(msg.what == handlerState){

                    byte[] rBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String readMessage = new String(rBuff, 0, msg.arg1);
                    handlerInfo.setText(readMessage);

                }

            }
        };
```